# Ripple and noise measurement of DC-DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, measurement

I am using the [TEP 75-2412WI-CMF](https://www.tracopower.com/products/tep75wi.pdf). One of the output specifications of this is 100mVp-p ripple and noise. They have mentioned 20MHz bandwidth.

Right now I am measuring the 5V output of this on an oscilloscope and getting ripple of 80-100mVp-p.

What is this 20MHz bandwidth?

[image]

Comment: Are you using an oscilloscope probe? Many probes have a long ground connection. In the vicinity of fast magnetic flux changes, your ripple measurement may include extra AC voltage that your circuits don't see. Some probes also have resonances in the 100 MHz ballpark that a *20MHz bandwidth limit* can partially reject.

Answer (score 5):

The de facto standard for power supply ripple and noise measurement uses 20 MHz bandwidth. It means that if you use oscilloscope and probes that can measure up to 1 GHz bandwidth for example, you must limit the bandwidth to 20 MHz. Most oscilloscopes have a 20 MHz bandwidth setting for this purpose.